# Dynamically added EditTexts and forcing the user to enter data on focus change

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have dynamically added 3 `EditTexts` on a `TableLayout`. Then on focus change through tab on emulator in `Eclipse`, I check if they are blank, if blank I need to set the focus to the `EditText` else it should move to the next.

The issue is that, focus moves to the next `EditText` and cursor allows entry into next field. Also both `EditTexts` get highlighted. Can someone help me with the proper way to change focus?

I though this would do the trick but it doesn't work. Again both the `EditTexts` are getting focussed as both are blank, causing focus listeners on both to be activated.

```
if(arrEdit.size()>0){
for(EditText etLot: arrEdit){
    etLot.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            String msg = null;
            EditText et = null;

            if(!hasFocus){
                for(int i=0;i< arrEdit.size();i++){
                    msg= ((TextView)arrTxtVw.get(i)).getText().toString();
                    System.out.println("Focus Changed on "+msg);
                    if((((EditText)v).length()>0)==false && ((EditText)v).getId()== arrEdit.get(i).getId()){
                        System.out.println("size is zero for "+msg);
                        (arrEdit.get(i)).requestFocus();
                        et=(arrEdit.get(i));
                        break;
                    }
                }

                TextView text = (TextView) lyout.findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setTextSize(15);
                text.setText(msg+"cannot be blank");
                Toast toast = new Toast(ctxref);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(1500);
                toast.setView(lyout);
                toast.show();
                final EditText ettemp = et;
                et.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        ettemp.requestFocus();

                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue setting focus on dynamically added edittexts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758819/issue-setting-focus-on-dynamically-added-edittexts)

Comment: Luksprog, I have deleted the previous question..

Comment: any one out there to help me out on this??

Comment: @user1645859: You should have edited your previous question instead of posting it again.